# Push subfolder to ftp using git-ftp

Tags: git, deployment, ftp, git-ftp

How can I push only a certain subfolder (the publish folder of html5 boilerplate) to a specified ftp directory using git-ftp?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

**A**

1. make the publish folder a git repository.
2. Use git ftp inside of that repo

**B (much better)**

use the [syncroot option](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/master/man/git-ftp.1.md#options) of git-ftp to specify the directory to sync from as if it were the git project root path.
In .git/config under [git-ftp] add

```
syncroot = publish/
```